# How to change the splash image of Lenovo Tab M10 (TB-X505X)?

Tags: lenovo, boot-animation

I have a Lenovo Tab M10 tablet. I successfully rooted it and changed its booting animation. Now I want to change its splash picture. I extract `splash.img` from `/dev/block/by-name/splash` with the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/block/by-name/splash of=/mnt/sdcard/
```

But can't get the image out of `splash.img`. I use the following commands to get images out:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24  -s 1280x800 -i splash.img -vframes 1 -y output_splash.png
```

and

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb565  -s 1280x800 -i splash.img -vframes 1 -y output_splash.png
```

And other commands that I found on the internet. But in all cases, the output image is wrong.

I want to get the image out to check whether the extracted partition is correct or not. However, a complete guide to changing the splash image is accepted.