# Changing boot & shutdown screen on Lenovo Tab M10 FHD Plus

Tags: lenovo, boot-animation

Can anyone help me with how to change the boot screen and shutdown screen on my Lenovo Tab M10 FHD Plus? It seems to me that I cannot change the files in the system. It won't let me edit them or replace them etc.

I've tried for hours with this and got nowhere. I tried changing files in system files but they're locked up and can't be edited or overwritten, etc. I tried an app that's meant to write over them for you with new animation files for start-up and shutdown, but that won't do the trick either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable avb/dm-verity manually on super partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233891/disable-avb-dm-verity-manually-on-super-partition)

Comment: [A similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245660/44325) hints that it needs root access to change the boot animation.